# I want to separate directory of register member in filemanager within member name

Tags: opencart2.x

- I add new member in store front(Not customer additional member)
- Make Login page and registration page for them
- After login member can upload their logo by file manager

My question is that file manager shows all images within catalog folder which is against policy because reg. member can see all images for catalog folder, so I want to solution for that.

I want to try to make one directory with member name and upload photo to that directory and only show by that member.

My opencart version is 2.1.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I get solution

set variable in filemanager.tpl

$('#button-upload').on('click', function()
 {
    ..
                var user_id='session->data['user_id']?>'; 
..

In ControllerCommonFileManager

i edit upload function

public function upload()
 {

```
    if(!file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/user/' . $this->session->data['user_id']))
        mkdir(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/user/' . $this->session->data['user_id'] , 0777);
    $path = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/user/' . $this->session->data['user_id'];

    $this->load->language('common/filemanager');

    $json = array();

    /* // Check user has permission
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'common/filemanager')) {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    } */

    // Make sure we have the correct directory
    if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
        $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/user/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');
    } else {
        $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';
    }
    $directory = $path;

    // Check its a directory
    if (!is_dir($directory)) {
        $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_directory');
    }

    if (!$json) {
        if (!empty($this->request->files['file']['name']) && is_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'])) {
            // Sanitize the filename
            $filename = basename(html_entity_decode($this->request->files['file']['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

            // Validate the filename length
            if ((utf8_strlen($filename) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($filename) > 255)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filename');
            }

            // Allowed file extension types
            $allowed = array(
                'jpg',
                'jpeg',
                'gif',
                'png'
            );

            if (!in_array(utf8_strtolower(utf8_substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 1)), $allowed)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');
            }

            // Allowed file mime types
            $allowed = array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png',
                'image/x-png',
                'image/gif'
            );

            if (!in_array($this->request->files['file']['type'], $allowed)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');
            }

            // Check to see if any PHP files are trying to be uploaded
            $content = file_get_contents($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name']);

            if (preg_match('/\<\?php/i', $content)) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_filetype');
            }

            // Return any upload error
            if ($this->request->files['file']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload_' . $this->request->files['file']['error']);
            }
        } else {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_upload');
        }
    }

    if (!$json) {
        move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['file']['tmp_name'], $directory . '/' . $filename);

        $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_uploaded');
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously if File manager is showing at front end it's mean you already copied it's files from respective admin folders to catalog folders.

In default file manager code is written for admin so it's shows all files but for your members, you have to add condition so that they can access only allowed folders like you are saying.
For this please edit you `catalog > controller > common > filemanager.php` file and search for this code

```
if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
    $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');
} else {
    $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog';
}
```

this `$directory` variable is responsible for showing those folders. So after updating this you can restrict your members.
Now you were saying, based on name will be good but i suggest name and member id combination will be good because same name can cause error !!
Now you have to get details of you current login member form table where you stored those. Like

```
$memberDetails = $this->db->query("your query")->row;
//Assuming $memberDetails have min 2 indexes -> ['id', 'name']
```

So your filemanager.php updated code will be

```
if (isset($this->request->get['directory'])) {
    $directory = rtrim(DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/' . $memberDetails['id'] . $memberDetails['name'] . '/' . str_replace(array('../', '..\\', '..'), '', $this->request->get['directory']), '/');
} else {
    $directory = DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog'. $memberDetails['id'] . $memberDetails['name'];
}
//added member details after catalog folder.
```

Like this you can add conditions for upload and delete too.

Note - Didn't tested but will work :)